# How to exclude one button from form validation with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

The form does validation on submit and if ok you can add a new value, modify an existing value, or delete. However, Delete gets interrupted by validation. The first part validation check is if a `newName` already exists in the `readName` select. Second part is just to make sure the text box isn't blank.  `newName` is populated based on `readName` selection. On delete validation complains because you are submitting a value that lives in the dropdown. How can Delete bypass validation?

```
<form action="lists" method="post" onsubmit="return validate(this)">

   <selects id="readName" name="readName" onchange="updateAction(this.form, 'read');this.form.submit()">                    
        <option  title="PETER" value="PETER">PETER</option>                           
        <option selected title="Will" value="Will">Will</option>
        <option  title="one" value="one">one</option>                        
   </select>
   <label class="padLeft15">Edit Name:</label>&nbsp;                              
   <input type="text" name="newName" id="newName" title="Will" value="Will" />

   <input class="marginRight10" id="new" type="submit" onclick="updateAction(this.form, 'new');" value="New" />
   <input class="marginRight10" id="save" type="submit" onclick="updateAction(this.form, 'save')" value="Save" />
   <input class="marginRight10" id="delete" type="submit" onclick="updateAction(this.form, 'delete')" value="Delete" />

</form>

<script>
function validate(form) {
var isValid = validateText(form.newName);
var exists= $("#readName option[value='"+ $("#newName").val()+"']").length > 0;

    if (exists) {
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "WHOAA, already have this in the list!!";
        return false;
    }
    if (!isValid) {
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Name must not be empty";
        return false;
    }
    return isValid;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the delete button to a button type so it won't submit.  Then override the click action for what occurs by manually passing your data.

```
<input class="marginRight10" id="delete" type="button" onclick="updateAction(this.form, 'delete')" value="Delete" />

$('body').on('click', '#delete', function () { 
     updateAction('#yourformid', 'delete')
});
```

Comment: Changing it to button should be sufficient if you continue to have 
`onclick="updateAction(this.form, 'delete')"` in the attribute. The above code makes multiple calls to same action from different points.